# Mix an anchor's underline style with an inline-block element

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have noticed that if an element, such as span or p, has a display of inline-block then it will cover the underline style of an anchor when placed inside.

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><span style="display:inline-block">test</span></a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><p style="display:inline-block">test</p></a>
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Post this as an answer.  I feel that it's the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to the style tag `text-decoration:inherit;`

Comment: This works flawlessly in Chrome.  However, in Firefox and IE the inline-block span has an underline that is slightly higher than the anchor's underline.

Comment: Please disregard my last comment.  This method works perfectly in all browsers.  See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uwZAX/3/) fiddle for a simple example.  My problem is that I am also using `overflow:hidden` (to implement an ellipsis) which causes the underline to be higher in FF/IE.  See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uwZAX/4/) fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

1) Move the style to the A-tag

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="display:inline-block">test</a>
```

or

2) Add underline to the child element

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"><p style="display:inline-block;text-decoration:underline">test</p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following style:

```
​a *:hover { text-decoration: underline }​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2e24v/)